# Assigning Back button event to form button in android

Tags: android-emulator

i have a form button in the form,which i need to perform basic action performed by the back button in the android emulator.
I know the key even is KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK

how to assign this to my button.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to it.
call the function  moveTaskToBack(true);
to get back to previous task.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't totally clear, but you probably just want to call [`finish()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) when your `Button` is clicked.